# How do I recognize distinct clients in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am building a game using node.js and socket.io, and I came across an issue. As you can see in the screenshot below, it asks for the user's name. Let's say I input John Doe. When the user clicks the enter button, it will send the name (John Doe) and the client id of the user (`socket.io.engine.id`) to the server, and will redirect to `play.html`. However, when I have navigated to `play.html`, how can I make it possible so that the server knows that the player who has navigated to `play.html` is John Doe and not somebody else on another computer?

[image]

---

Server console:

[image]

Comment: You need a session cookie or a query string parameter.

Comment: @Slaks I was thinking about the query string parameter, but a user could easily modify that and it doesn't seem very secure

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible to trust data from a client.  What attack are you trying to prevent?

Comment: Not so much of an attack as maintaining a "black box" and also I know that the data from the client should not be trusted but it seems odd that there's no way to do this without a string parameter

Comment: To do what? You're literally asking to trust the client to identify itself.  Why does that seem odd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First - you should **not** navigate away once the connection is made. You can easily integrate that screen into the game. You can get any response from the server and **then** show the screen dynamically.

Second - because you're making that 'new connection' (after redirecting), it's up to the server to tell the client **which name he's using**. As someone mentioned in the comments - you cannot trust the client! The problem here is that new connection means new socket id (therefore you should not make new connection -- no redirect).

A little mention - there are tons of way to tell the server (from the client) which name he's using. You can use local storage / cookies or whatever you want on the client side. Then you can connect to specific namespace, join specific room or send specific command stating the name. Again - this is not trustworthy.

If it's **that** much needed, you should use some kind of session. Because of the way connection works (check handshake) socket io actually makes http request the first time and then upgrades to sockets. Therefore you can read the cookies of the browse on the server-side. The easiest way is to set cookie and then read it. If we're talking about security - this could not be trusted, as it can be modified.

What you should do is somehow authenticate the user (using passport for example) and storing session id into the cookie. This way user cannot easily modify it (as it's pretty scrambled). Session id is stored in database together with the user name. On each connection you get the cookie from the socket, get it's session id, query the database, get the pair (session id <-> user name) and then you know the name of this particular user. If the client needs it - send it somehow (emit for example). If there is no session (or session is not found in database which means user edited it) - user is not logged in.

This is by any means way more complicated than I think you would need. My advice would be simply not to redirect and therefore be sure that new connection = new user name, end of story. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to a session, you could issue a JWT to the user before redirecting to the new page. Before page load, the server can verify the JWT signature and payload, so the user name (payload) can be trusted.

JWTs can be added to request headers, bodies or query strings. They just don't work if you authenticate on a page and open a second browser tab/window, because then you can't inject them in these parts before request. In those cases, you need a cookie.

Example and information:

https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken

Comment: Oh, that's pretty nice suggestion! I've recently used it, but somehow forgot to mention :) They are extremely easy to setup and provide simple auth, but are still vulnerable, especially if you set high expiration time. Nevertheless - it's a nice option to try, because you won't need cookie parser, session storage, all that bunch of things. Simple functions to generate and validate the token will work. Good job @noderman!

Comment: Thanks! I think we'll see more and more of that on an "API-first" world, where you need authentication without cookies. Cheers.